# Are there ways I can synchronize a Xamarin Forms application with a SQLite database from one device to another?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I realize this is not something simple but does anyone know of any good examples out there that demonstrate this functionality.

On my phone I have a SQLite database and I would like to allow a user to login to a central database and have this data duplicated to any other device they login to.  Not sure if this helps but I am using appcenter.ms and I did see that offers Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: ,According to your description, you want to copy one sqlite database in another device, if you do this, I think it is difficult to sync sqlite data in different device, so I suggest you can use Icloud, like using firebase.

Comment: Thanks, I will boost up this question with a big bounty soon and then perhaps someone can help out with an example or point me to some examples that I could start from.

Comment: if you have one solution, please share here, thanks.